# Very simple: requiring images in webpack and Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am having some trouble requiring images in my Angular 2 webpack applicaiton.

I have tried three or four image loaders but I don't seem to be able configure them properly and the result in the HTML is incorrect.

For example, at the moment I have:

```
<img src='${require("../images/logo.png")}'>
```

The file containing this image is part of a template which is required like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'appstore-app',
    directives: [ ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    styles: [require('../sass/appstore.scss').toString()],
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
```

This results in an error in the browser:

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/$%7Brequire(%22../images/logo.png%22)%7D
```

My loader for images image my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
{ test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=50000&name=[path][name].[ext]" }
```

I may well be muddling syntaxes here but as I've said I've tried a few methods. This doesn't work. The $require makes it into the HTML verbatim without being transformed!

How do I either copy the images to the build folder or package them as a DataURL?

Please help!

Comment: Do you have solved this? How?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like so. I know you figured it out but for future reference you don't need to use require; use ____Url instead. Require caused me issues with other libraries using webpack for loading assets....it's not needed.

```
     <img src="../images/logo.png">

//note styleUrl and templateUrl since you have a path not inline with component
        @Component({
            selector: 'appstore-app',
            directives: [ ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
            styleUrl: ['../sass/appstore.scss'],
            templateUrl: './app.component.html'
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
<img src={{appstore-logo}}>
```

and your component code is

```
@Component({
    selector: 'appstore-app',
    directives: [ ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    styles: [require('../sass/appstore.scss').toString()],
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppStoreComponent {
    private appStoreImage: any = require('../images/logo.png');
}
```

You must insert this code before applying this Component.

```
declare function require(name: string): string;
```

this code in your AppModule

Please let me know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

There's no need to $require the src in the image; webpack will handle this with the right loader.

Comment: I created a extra-webpack.config.js and attempted to reference a url-loader for `jpe?g|png\gif`and its not automagically base64'ing a `<img src=...`.  I've spent a number of hours dorking around with it. If someone has an idea it would be appreciated.

Answer (score -5):

I did not proof check this, but this is the general idea:

Require it to a variable in the respective controller in the following manner

```
$scope.imageSrc = require('../images/logo.png');
```

And then in your template, the imageSrc would either be base64 encoded or the data url as per your loader config.

```
<img src='{{imageSrc}}'>
```

Comment: There is no `$scope` in Angular 2.